# Requiring JS files at bottom of document presents usability issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, boilerplate

This is more of a best practice question.

I recently began using the [HTML5 boilerplate](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate) for a bunch of projects I have been doing but recently discovered something that could be an issue.  Another developer brought to my attention that it may be an issue loading JS files at the bottom of the document due to certain functionality not working on page load( ie. form using jQuery $.ajax) and in turn presenting some usability issues.  I wanted to get some opinions on what is the best way to address common issues like this that may arise. I have been using HTML5 boilerplate as I know Paul Irish and friends have really thought out this system and are constantly improving upon it.

**Example issue:** Home page of site has newsletter sign up form that uses the jQuery `$.post` function to submit values of form.  User has access to enter values and press submit but this will render no action as js is not loaded presenting usability issues.

What is the best way to work with JS included at the bottom of the site?

Comment: @jnolte Are you saying that it takes more then a 2-3 seconds for `DOMContentLoaded` to fire on your page?

Comment: I don't understand - your JS files will be loaded in a couple of seconds regardless of where you put them. How does a user have time to fill a form in a couple of seconds? If you mean your code literally doesn't work at all when you place the files at the bottom of the page, then there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: @Sime Vidas yes, that is correct.  @thirtydot there is nothing wrong with my code. it is entering an email address, that only takes a second.  This technically will not be an issue 99% of the time but what about the other 1% of the time.

Comment: @jnolte It takes more than a couple of seconds for the HTML source code of your page to be parsed? Why?

Comment: @jnolte: The only way a user can enter an email address inside of 2 seconds AND hit Submit is if they: already have it in their clipboard and paste it in, their browser is filling it in for them, or they are [The Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(comics)).

Comment: @Sime no, it takes about 1-2 seconds for js to load. I misunderstood your question

Comment: @jnolte Nobody clicks on submit buttons 2 seconds after the page has **started** loading. And by then jQuery should become available.

Comment: @jnolte Where do you load the jQuery file from? Google CDN delivers the file in 200ms.

Comment: @Sime I find that statement to be untrue, what about a search form that is cleared via js.  Again this is not for the general user, I was looking for best practice  (ie rendering forms disabled until js loads, etc) @sime loading from Google CDN.

Comment: @jnolte Hm, the search form should be empty on page load anyway, what do you mean? On this page (Stack Overflow) it takes 700ms for jQuery to become available. Trust me, nobody is able to input an e-mail address and click on the submit button in 700ms.

Comment: @Sime that is a relative number and based on your connection speed, there are many reasons this could become an issue, for instance the office that I am in currently has issues with internet speeds during upload that absolutely no-one can do anything about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be this:

- put all your SCRIPT elements at the bottom of the page
- let the jQuery script be in the first SCRIPT element
- let the second SCRIPT element contain a ready() handler for the behavior that you want to become available as soon as possible

Like so:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>
    $(function() {
        // bind the handler to the newsletter submit button
        // etc.
    });
</script>
<!-- all other external and inline scripts should be below this line -->
<script src="pluginA.js"></script>
<script src="pluginB.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        // other page load code
    });
</script>
```

This is the best you can do.

Btw, users expect the page to be broken for the first couple of seconds anyway. I experience this all the time on Facebook, Youtube, ...

Comment: +1 an example of the broken page is right here at SO. When you click on the little red icon indicating responses before the page has loaded it takes you to stack exchange rather than showing your inbox.

Comment: Accepted as correct answer, I thought there may have been some other work around that would work better.  In the end I guess my conclusion is this issue is not really an issue at all and normal interactivity.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you shouldn't be using JS as the sole enabler of an action/activity. Your site needs to be made with functionality that will work regardless of whether JS is present or not. JS just needs to add that extra layer. If you follow this rule, it won't matter where you include your JS.

At any rate, if you do include it at the bottom as @thrtydot mentioned, there is only a few seconds difference (unless your HTML is so long that there is a big gap between the top of the page and area where JS is loaded - in which case you have bigger concerns to worry about) and shouldn't matter in the long run

Answer (score 0):

With your Ajax form you are probably binding a submit or click event to fire the Ajax call, right? And that binding can only be done when the DOM has loaded (using the jquery ready method). So your code is getting executed after the HTML body has rendered, which means you could load it at the bottom of the body.

If you are seeing problems where users try to submit before the Ajax functionality has bound then you could have a visually 'disabled' state on the button until the binding occurs.

However, by loading script files in the head you block rendering of anything so users get a blank page. Generally it's a better experience to get the content even if you have to wait a moment for the functionality.